# python && unix permissions (gitlab)

Tags: permissions, python

I have directory  `/home/git/repositories` with rights 770 and uid=git,gid=git

```
user1@gitserver:~$ ls -la /home/git/ | grep repo
drwxrws--- 42 git  git  4096 Jun 30 17:02 repositories
```

I have user 'www-data', which added into 'git' group

```
user1@gitserver:~$ id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),1001(git)
user1@gitserver:~$ id -G www-data
33 1001
```

From 'www-data' user running python-script which calling    `os.listdir('/home/git/repositories')`   and failing with message
`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/git/repositories/'`

```
def functn()
    repo_dir = '/home/git/repositories'
    logg('CURRENT USER: getresuid && getresgid')
    logg(os.getresuid())
    logg(os.getresgid())
    logg('CURRENT USER: getgroups')
    logg(os.getgroups())
    logg(os.listdir(repo_dir))  <-- here is fault
```

Here is output:

```
'CURRENT USER: getresuid && getresgid'
(33, 33, 33)
(33, 33, 33)

'CURRENT USER: getgroups'
[33]                            <-- 'git' group not showing =(
```

User 'www-data' added to git group. **Why he cant list that directory?!**

upd here is **namei -mo /home/git/repositories**:

```
user1@gitserver:~$ namei -mo /home/git/repositories
f: /home/git/repositories
 drwxr-xr-x root root /
 drwxr-xr-x root root home
 drwxr-xr-x git  git  git
 drwxrws--- git  git  repositories
```

Comment: The permissions of `/home/git` also matter. Add the output of `namei -mo /home/git/repositories` to your question. Also, you may need to restart the web server process for new group memberships to take effect.

Comment: @muru   `user1@gitserver:~$ id -G www-data`  say:    `33 1001` but    `user1@gitserver:~$ id -g www-data`  say:    `33`

So, it mean that effective groups not contain 'git'. Is restart web-server can help me? Or i should reboot computer?

Comment: There can only be *one* effective group ID, so that's correct. However, if the process started before you added `www-data` to the new group, it think won't be affected. If you can restart just the web server, try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216351/python-unix-permissions-gitlab/216365#comment367135_216351) was right; the web server was started before I added `www-data` to the `git` group. The web server was restarted when I rebooted for other reasons and the problem went away.